# python regex for extracting java comment

Tags: python, regex, comments

I am parsing Java source code using Python. I need to extract the comment text from the source.
I have tried the following.

Take 1:

`cmts = re.findall(r'/\*\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/', lines)`

Returns: blanks `[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']`

Take 2: (added a grouping bracket around the regex)

`cmts = re.findall(r'(/\*\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/)', lines)`

Returns

Single line comment (example only):

`('/**\n\n     * initialise the tag with the colors and the tag name\n\n     */', ' ')`

Multi line comment (example only):

`('/**\n\n     * Get the color related to a specified tag\n\n     * @param tag the tag that we want to get the colour for\n\n     * @return color of the tag in String\n\n     */', ' ')`

I am interested only in `initialise the tag with the colors and the tag name` 
or `Get the color related to a specified tag, @param tag the tag that we want to get the colour for, @return color of the tag in String`
and am not able to get my head around it. Please give me some pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract comments (everything between `/**` and `*/`), you can use:

```
re.findall(r'\*\*(.*?)\*\/', text, re.S)
```

(note how capture group can be simplified if `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` is used, when dot matches also newlines).

Then, for each match you can strip multiple whitespace/`*`, and replace `\n` with `,`:

```
def comments(text):
    for comment in re.findall(r'\*\*(.*?)\*\/', text, re.S):
        yield re.sub('\n+', ',', re.sub(r'[ *]+', ' ', comment).strip())
```

For example:

```
>>> list(comments('/**\n\n     * Get the color related to a specified tag\n\n     * @param tag the tag that we want to get the colour for\n\n     * @return color of the tag in String\n\n     */'))
['Get the color related to a specified tag, @param tag the tag that we want to get the colour for, @return color of the tag in String']
```